# Django Rest Framework Without Database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to setup a simple API using Django Rest Framework, the problem is that my API does not have any database but the framework won't work without database setting.

Here is my Django Rest Framework configuration in `settings.py`:

```python
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'provider',
    'django_nose',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
}
```

The error which I got is:

> ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured.
>   "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is
>   improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings
>   documentation for more details.

Is there any minimal settings which does not include `django.contrib.contenttypes` and `django.contrib.auth`?

Comment: When did you get that error ? Why do you need contenttypes application ?

Comment: Note that I have some API that don't use DB and haven't ran into that issue.

Comment: @Linovia I don't need contenttypes application and auth application, but it won't work without them, can you post a minimal django rest framework settings which does not hav any DB and will be only used as an API?

Comment: @Linovia It occurs when the view is trying to perform authentication

Comment: You can't have default authentication without DB. You'll have to write your own.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want any authentication.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The actual cause of the problem is that DRF trys to add a `user` attribute to the `request`. Briefly mentioned in the documentation, the mechanism is as follows:

> **[How authentication is determined](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#how-authentication-is-determined)**
>
> If no class authenticates, `request.user` will be set to an instance of
>   `django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser`

So it needed the `django.contrib.auth` application to run correctly, consequently `django.contrib.auth` requires a working configuration of Database to be able to perform.

The solution to this problem is to set the settings `UNAUTHENTICATED_USER` property to `None`.

Configuration will be like this after the changes:

```python
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
    'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER': None,
}
```

Comment: For me django rest framework APIView requires django.contrib.contenttypes, which is turned off. Error is RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS. The solution with UNAUTHENTICATED_USER works in the case too!

Answer (score 21):

If you are really forced to use a database but you don't want to, you can use `:memory:` with the SQLite backend, like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    }
}
```

This uses an in-memory database, so that your filesystem won't be touched.

Because memory is volatile, you might need to run migrations automatically every time your web app starts.

Comment: Can you describe more?

Comment: In short, instead of using disk space on server, you will use RAM. That is all. However, there is no need for doing this. Some suggested to use a file and you will not need to use it. You can use this option just to not see sqlite file and it will be deleted after shutting down. Both options are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any option. `DATABASES` dict should be in `settings.py`. You can use this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to setup the API without any database, even as small as sqlite :)

Comment: Why? Is there any reason for that?

Comment: It is redundant, there will be no another use for it.

Comment: Well, in this case you should create a big mock of database backend. Or extract model layer from database on your own from Django.

Answer (score -1):

[not tested] maybe you could use a dummy backend. I see there's one from django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}
```

Comment: ahhh hmm or maybe not.. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py this is actually what it's complaining, you could probablly create one like this that just "pass" instead of raising an exception.. who knows it might work